# Jackson.Парсинг простой, а не JSON строки

Tags: java, android, jackson

Интересует, можно ли скормить обычную строку Джексону? И потом уже построить 2 списка , по значениям? Вот строка которую я получил, после парсинга JSON. `

> [{"id":3,"name":"Replay"},{"id":4,"name":"Replica"},{"id":2,"name":"Vianor"},{"id":5,"name":"Kosei"},{"id":12,"name":"Invader"},{"id":8,"name":"MANSORY"},{"id":13,"name":"RAYS"},{"id":14,"name":"VISSOL"}]`

Парсинг осуществляется таким образом:

```
String make =pojo_params.getData().getMake();
```

Если нет, то как лучше поступить? ЛУчшей идеи, кроме как скормить её опять Джексону у меня не приходит.
На всякий случай прикреплю оригинал JSON, чтобы было понятно откуда эта строка у меня взялась.

```
{
"success": true,
"data": {
    "auto": "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Acura\"},{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"AUDI\"},{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"Bentley\"},{\"id\":6,\"name\":\"BMW\"},{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"Cadillac\"},{\"id\":10,\"name\":\"Chevrolet\"},{\"id\":11,\"name\":\"Chrysler\"},{\"id\":12,\"name\":\"Citroen\"},{\"id\":17,\"name\":\"Dodge\"},{\"id\":18,\"name\":\"Fiat\"},{\"id\":19,\"name\":\"Ford\"},{\"id\":21,\"name\":\"Geely\"},{\"id\":65,\"name\":\"Gmc\"},{\"id\":22,\"name\":\"Great Wall\"},{\"id\":23,\"name\":\"Honda\"},{\"id\":25,\"name\":\"Hyundai\"},{\"id\":26,\"name\":\"Infiniti\"},{\"id\":27,\"name\":\"Jaguar\"},{\"id\":28,\"name\":\"Jeep\"},{\"id\":30,\"name\":\"Kia\"},{\"id\":33,\"name\":\"Landrover\"},{\"id\":34,\"name\":\"Lexus\"},{\"id\":38,\"name\":\"Mazda\"},{\"id\":39,\"name\":\"Mercedes\"},{\"id\":41,\"name\":\"MINI\"},{\"id\":42,\"name\":\"Mitsubishi\"},{\"id\":66,\"name\":\"Mustang\"},{\"id\":44,\"name\":\"Nissan\"},{\"id\":45,\"name\":\"Opel\"},{\"id\":46,\"name\":\"Peugeot\"},{\"id\":47,\"name\":\"Porsche\"},{\"id\":48,\"name\":\"Renault\"},{\"id\":54,\"name\":\"Skoda\"},{\"id\":51,\"name\":\"SsangYong\"},{\"id\":55,\"name\":\"Subaru\"},{\"id\":56,\"name\":\"Suzuki\"},{\"id\":57,\"name\":\"Toyota\"},{\"id\":60,\"name\":\"Volkswagen\"},{\"id\":61,\"name\":\"Volvo\"}]",
    "make": "[{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"Replay\"},{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"Replica\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Vianor\"},{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"Kosei\"},{\"id\":12,\"name\":\"Invader\"},{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"MANSORY\"},{\"id\":13,\"name\":\"RAYS\"},{\"id\":14,\"name\":\"VISSOL\"}]",
    "size": "[{\"id\":13,\"name\":13},{\"id\":14,\"name\":14},{\"id\":15,\"name\":15},{\"id\":16,\"name\":16},{\"id\":17,\"name\":17},{\"id\":18,\"name\":18},{\"id\":19,\"name\":19},{\"id\":20,\"name\":20},{\"id\":21,\"name\":21},{\"id\":22,\"name\":22}]",
    "rim": "[{\"id\":\"5.0\",\"name\":\"5.0\"},{\"id\":\"5.5\",\"name\":\"5.5\"},{\"id\":\"6.0\",\"name\":\"6.0\"},{\"id\":\"6.5\",\"name\":\"6.5\"},{\"id\":\"7.0\",\"name\":\"7.0\"},{\"id\":\"7.5\",\"name\":\"7.5\"},{\"id\":\"8.0\",\"name\":\"8.0\"},{\"id\":\"8.5\",\"name\":\"8.5\"},{\"id\":\"9.0\",\"name\":\"9.0\"},{\"id\":\"9.5\",\"name\":\"9.5\"},{\"id\":\"10.0\",\"name\":\"10.0\"},{\"id\":\"10.5\",\"name\":\"10.5\"},{\"id\":\"11.0\",\"name\":\"11.0\"}]",
    "psd": "[{\"id\":12,\"name\":\"4x100\"},{\"id\":9,\"name\":\"4x108\"},{\"id\":14,\"name\":\"4x114.3\"},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"4x98\"},{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"5x100\"},{\"id\":15,\"name\":\"5x105\"},{\"id\":7,\"name\":\"5x108\"},{\"id\":6,\"name\":\"5x110\"},{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"5x112\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"5x114.3\"},{\"id\":25,\"name\":\"5x115\"},{\"id\":33,\"name\":\"5x118\"},{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"5x120\"},{\"id\":35,\"name\":\"5x120-130\"},{\"id\":26,\"name\":\"5x127\"},{\"id\":11,\"name\":\"5x130\"},{\"id\":16,\"name\":\"5x139.7\"},{\"id\":19,\"name\":\"5x150\"},{\"id\":27,\"name\":\"5x160\"},{\"id\":20,\"name\":\"6x114.3\"},{\"id\":31,\"name\":\"6x127\"},{\"id\":29,\"name\":\"6x130\"},{\"id\":168,\"name\":\"6x135\"},{\"id\":13,\"name\":\"6x139.7\"}]",
    "et": "[{\"id\":\"2.0\",\"name\":\"2.0\"},{\"id\":\"5.0\",\"name\":\"5.0\"},{\"id\":\"7.0\",\"name\":\"7.0\"},{\"id\":\"10.0\",\"name\":\"10.0\"},{\"id\":\"14.0\",\"name\":\"14.0\"},{\"id\":\"15.0\",\"name\":\"15.0\"},{\"id\":\"16.0\",\"name\":\"16.0\"},{\"id\":\"18.0\",\"name\":\"18.0\"},{\"id\":\"19.0\",\"name\":\"19.0\"},{\"id\":\"20.0\",\"name\":\"20.0\"},{\"id\":\"20.5\",\"name\":\"20.5\"},{\"id\":\"21.0\",\"name\":\"21.0\"},{\"id\":\"23.0\",\"name\":\"23.0\"},{\"id\":\"24.0\",\"name\":\"24.0\"},{\"id\":\"25.0\",\"name\":\"25.0\"},{\"id\":\"26.0\",\"name\":\"26.0\"},{\"id\":\"27.0\",\"name\":\"27.0\"},{\"id\":\"28.0\",\"name\":\"28.0\"},{\"id\":\"29.0\",\"name\":\"29.0\"},{\"id\":\"30.0\",\"name\":\"30.0\"},{\"id\":\"31.0\",\"name\":\"31.0\"},{\"id\":\"32.0\",\"name\":\"32.0\"},{\"id\":\"33.0\",\"name\":\"33.0\"},{\"id\":\"34.0\",\"name\":\"34.0\"},{\"id\":\"34.5\",\"name\":\"34.5\"},{\"id\":\"35.0\",\"name\":\"35.0\"},{\"id\":\"36.0\",\"name\":\"36.0\"},{\"id\":\"37.0\",\"name\":\"37.0\"},{\"id\":\"38.0\",\"name\":\"38.0\"},{\"id\":\"39.0\",\"name\":\"39.0\"},{\"id\":\"39.5\",\"name\":\"39.5\"},{\"id\":\"40.0\",\"name\":\"40.0\"},{\"id\":\"41.0\",\"name\":\"41.0\"},{\"id\":\"41.3\",\"name\":\"41.3\"},{\"id\":\"41.5\",\"name\":\"41.5\"},{\"id\":\"42.0\",\"name\":\"42.0\"},{\"id\":\"42.5\",\"name\":\"42.5\"},{\"id\":\"43.0\",\"name\":\"43.0\"},{\"id\":\"43.8\",\"name\":\"43.8\"},{\"id\":\"44.0\",\"name\":\"44.0\"},{\"id\":\"45.0\",\"name\":\"45.0\"},{\"id\":\"45.5\",\"name\":\"45.5\"},{\"id\":\"46.0\",\"name\":\"46.0\"},{\"id\":\"47.0\",\"name\":\"47.0\"},{\"id\":\"47.5\",\"name\":\"47.5\"},{\"id\":\"48.0\",\"name\":\"48.0\"},{\"id\":\"48.5\",\"name\":\"48.5\"},{\"id\":\"49.0\",\"name\":\"49.0\"},{\"id\":\"49.5\",\"name\":\"49.5\"},{\"id\":\"50.0\",\"name\":\"50.0\"},{\"id\":\"51.0\",\"name\":\"51.0\"},{\"id\":\"52.0\",\"name\":\"52.0\"},{\"id\":\"52.5\",\"name\":\"52.5\"},{\"id\":\"53.0\",\"name\":\"53.0\"},{\"id\":\"54.0\",\"name\":\"54.0\"},{\"id\":\"55.0\",\"name\":\"55.0\"},{\"id\":\"56.0\",\"name\":\"56.0\"},{\"id\":\"57.0\",\"name\":\"57.0\"},{\"id\":\"58.0\",\"name\":\"58.0\"},{\"id\":\"59.0\",\"name\":\"59.0\"},{\"id\":\"60.0\",\"name\":\"60.0\"},{\"id\":\"62.0\",\"name\":\"62.0\"},{\"id\":\"65.0\",\"name\":\"65.0\"},{\"id\":\"66.0\",\"name\":\"66.0\"},{\"id\":\"68.0\",\"name\":\"68.0\"}]",
    "dia": "[{\"id\":\"54.1\",\"name\":\"54.1\"},{\"id\":\"56.1\",\"name\":\"56.1\"},{\"id\":\"56.6\",\"name\":\"56.6\"},{\"id\":\"57.1\",\"name\":\"57.1\"},{\"id\":\"58.1\",\"name\":\"58.1\"},{\"id\":\"60.1\",\"name\":\"60.1\"},{\"id\":\"63.3\",\"name\":\"63.3\"},{\"id\":\"63.4\",\"name\":\"63.4\"},{\"id\":\"64.1\",\"name\":\"64.1\"},{\"id\":\"65.1\",\"name\":\"65.1\"},{\"id\":\"66.1\",\"name\":\"66.1\"},{\"id\":\"66.6\",\"name\":\"66.6\"},{\"id\":\"66.9\",\"name\":\"66.9\"},{\"id\":\"67.1\",\"name\":\"67.1\"},{\"id\":\"70.1\",\"name\":\"70.1\"},{\"id\":\"70.6\",\"name\":\"70.6\"},{\"id\":\"71.1\",\"name\":\"71.1\"},{\"id\":\"71.5\",\"name\":\"71.5\"},{\"id\":\"71.6\",\"name\":\"71.6\"},{\"id\":\"72.6\",\"name\":\"72.6\"},{\"id\":\"73.1\",\"name\":\"73.1\"},{\"id\":\"74.1\",\"name\":\"74.1\"},{\"id\":\"76.1\",\"name\":\"76.1\"},{\"id\":\"77.7\",\"name\":\"77.7\"},{\"id\":\"77.8\",\"name\":\"77.8\"},{\"id\":\"78.1\",\"name\":\"78.1\"},{\"id\":\"84.1\",\"name\":\"84.1\"},{\"id\":\"86.8\",\"name\":\"86.8\"},{\"id\":\"89.1\",\"name\":\"89.1\"},{\"id\":\"93.1\",\"name\":\"93.1\"},{\"id\":\"100.1\",\"name\":\"100.1\"},{\"id\":\"106.1\",\"name\":\"106.1\"},{\"id\":\"106.2\",\"name\":\"106.2\"},{\"id\":\"108.1\",\"name\":\"108.1\"},{\"id\":\"110.1\",\"name\":\"110.1\"},{\"id\":\"110.2\",\"name\":\"110.2\"},{\"id\":\"110.5\",\"name\":\"110.5\"}]"
}
```

Comment: замените `make` на `"make"`, добавьте в начало строки `{`, а в конец `}` и будет вам JSON

Comment: А как вы вообще с исходной строки получили ту строку? В оригинале `make` с `"` идет...

Comment: @AGS17 59 Вообще то у меня получилось без make вовсе), для наглядности добавил, а получилось 
String make =pojo_params.getData().getMake();

И на выходе просто 
[{"id":3,"name":"Replay"},{"id":4,"name":"Replica"},{"id":2,"name":"Vianor"},{"id":5,"name":"Kosei"},{"id":12,"name":"Invader"},{"id":8,"name":"MANSORY"},{"id":13,"name":"RAYS"},{"id":14,"name":"VISSOL"}]

Или я какие-то костыли выдумываю?)

Comment: @rjhdby . Что-то я на этом заступорился, а ординарные скобки, я так понял, что не подойдут? {'make': [{"id":3,"name":"Replay"}? А то не понимаю, как их добавить.

Comment: А конечная то цель какая? Как вы собираетесь работать с этими данными?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создай модель для объекта который содержит *id,name* (назаваем её IdNameEntity)

```
public class IdNameEntity {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Ниже демо как парсить твой JSON:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
//other imports

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String content = "[{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"Replay\"},{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"Replica\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Vianor\"},{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"Kosei\"},{\"id\":12,\"name\":\"Invader\"},{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"MANSORY\"},{\"id\":13,\"name\":\"RAYS\"},{\"id\":14,\"name\":\"VISSOL\"}]";
        IdNameEntity[] idNameEntities = mapper.readValue(content, IdNameEntity[].class);
    }
}
```

Если надо получить список из масива:

```
List<IdNameEntity> list = Arrays.asList(idNameEntities);
```

Answer (score 1):

Автор вы делаете проблему на ровном месте.
Парсить JSON из строки, которая приходит по HTTP вы уже умеете.
Здесь все то же самое. Вот вам строка.

```
String make =pojo_params.getData().getMake();
```

Скормите ее парсеру и он вернет вам массив элементов.
Все абсолютно то же самое.

Просто надо понять, что ваш оригинальный JSON содержит некоторые строковые поля, содержимое которых по сути JSON, просто их надо распарсить отдельно.